# Executing a command on delimited lines

Tags: regular-expression, ex-mode

How   can  I   run  a   command   on  all lines   delimited,  say   by
`\begin{otherlanguage}` and `\end{otherlanguage}`?

For example,

```
1 This line should not be affected,
2 \begin{otherlanguage}
3 but this should;
4 \end{otherlanguage}
5 this should not.
```

(The cmd could be `norm A test`.)

Comment: Could you give us a workable example?

Comment: @romainl, yes, sorry if I was unclear.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use pattern delimiter for this:

```
:/first/,/second/norm dd
```

You can use any search pattern around the `,`.

If you want to use only the inside of the matched patterns, use + and - like so:

```
:/first/+1,/second/-1 norm dd
```

Comment: Very nice. I found adding `g` at the beginning helps if there are more than one set of delimiters.

Comment: I wonder whether something similar could be used to make a visual selection?

Comment: Interesting, you should be able by modifying the marks `<` and `>`, I think it's worth another question ;)

Answer (score 5):

A more specific answer (since you seem to be editing a TeX file): if you use the `vimtex` plugin (although `LaTeX-Box` also has this IIRC), you can easily select the whole environment (without the `\begin` and `\end` marker lines) using the *inside environment* text object (`ie`). So, assuming the cursor is somewhere *inside* the `otherlanguage` environment, your example can be "solved" with something like:

```
vie:norm A test
```

For more vimtex mappings, see `:h vimtex-default-mappings`.